# Impala find_in_set to match LIKE with percentage sign

Tags: sql, regex, impala

Is there a way to match `zz-10%` in `find_in_set`?

For example:

```
select find_in_set('zz-1000','zz-10%,zz-2000,zz-3000');
```

This should return `1` but Impala doesn't support it.
I am wondering if there is some trick with Regex to workaround? The `find_in_set` seems to do only exact match.

Ideally this should return `1` only as I want to avoid hardcoding a bunch of `zz-10%` variations.

This is the definition of this function from https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/impala_string_functions.html

> find_in_set(string str, string strList)
>
> Purpose: Returns the position
>   (starting from 1) of the first occurrence of a specified string within
>   a comma-separated string. Returns NULL if either argument is NULL, 0
>   if the search string is not found, or 0 if the search string contains
>   a comma. Return type: int

I cannot change `zz-1000` (the first param) because it's basically a Column. I could do a bunch of IF / CASE WHEN though if there is a way.

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

I tried this:

```
select find_in_set('zz-1000','zz-10\d+,zz-2000,zz-3000');
```

And got this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
| find_in_set('zz-1000', 'zz-10\d+,zz-2000,zz-3000') |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 0                                                  |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

So that doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with impala. Is `%` just a wildcard? If so, you could use `zz-10\d+` meaning zz-10 followed by one or more numerical characters.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I had UPDATE 1 posted.

Comment: that's because you mixed them up. Try `find_in_set('zz-10\d+', 'zz-1000,zz-200,zz-3000')` This will only work if find_in_set supports regex patterns though...

Comment: From what I've seen online it's not looking like it's supported. [Maybe this question can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130690/mysql-usage-of-regexp-instead-of-find-in-set)

Comment: That doesn't work either :( I am thinking a workaround by search for `%` chars in the second param and manually remove it. Then "cut" the length of the search string?!

Comment: try checking out that other question I linked

Comment: That gave me False. But even if it works, I need to get the Index though.

Answer (score 1):

What about to use `REGEXP_LIKE` function:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| regexp_like('zz-1000', 'zz-10\\d+$|zz-2000') |
+----------------------------------------------+
| true                                         |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

When you have a static number of strings to compare, we can try this:

```
SELECT CASE
   WHEN regexp_like('zz-1000', 'zz-10\\d+$') THEN 1
   WHEN regexp_like('zz-1000', 'zz-2000')    THEN 2
   ELSE 0
   END;
```

Comment: Sure but how would I make it to give me the Index return?

Comment: @HP I updated the answer with a solution using CASE expression. Hope, it will work for you.

Comment: That might work but the number of items in this list `'zz-10%,zz-2000,zz-3000'` could go to a hundred...

Comment: In Impala, I am wondering if there is a way to split the comma delimited string into rows and do regexp_like on each row? Then that would be easier than using `find_in_set`